# Having the first child open in accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="accordionButton">
    <span>Accordion Button</span><span class="plusMinus">+</span>
</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">
        <p>Stuff in the Accordion</p>
    </div>

<div class="accordionButton">
    <span>Accordion Button</span><span class="plusMinus">+</span>
</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">
        <p>Stuff in the Accordion</p>
    </div>
```

And I want the first tab accordionContent box to be open when the page is visited. But when clicking others, it'll slide up and open other content. How can I modify the code so the first accorionContent box is open?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accordionButton').click(function() {
        $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');
        $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
        $('.plusMinus').text('+');
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).addClass('on');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            $(this).children('.plusMinus').text('-');
         } 
     });
    $('.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('over');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('over');
    });
    $('.accordionContent').hide();

});
```

I tried

```
.accordionContent:first-child{
  display:block;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/Na5FY/110/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try adding this

```
$(".accordionContent").first().show();
```

after your

```
$(".accordionContent").hide();
```

Comment: Can you mark this as answer? Also, it is a good practice to store $(".accordionContent") once in a variable and refer it later. Right now we are querying the DOM repeatedly. This is bad for performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this at the end of your javascript:

```
$('.accordionButton:first-child').click();
```

Final Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accordionButton').click(function() {
        $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');
        $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
        $('.plusMinus').text('+');
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).addClass('on');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            $(this).children('.plusMinus').text('-');
         } 
     });
    $('.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('over');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('over');
    });
    $('.accordionContent').hide();

    $('.accordionButton:first-child').click();

});
```

Comment: it doesn't change the plus to minus and you would need to specify where to put it to not keep it open

Answer (score 0):

Try this one;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.accordionButton:eq(0)').trigger('click'); // the new line

$('.accordionButton').click(function() {
    $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');
    $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
    $('.plusMinus').text('+');
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        $(this).children('.plusMinus').text('-');
     } 
});

$('.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');
});
$('.accordionContent').hide();

});
```

Add on class the DOM is ready for the first .accordionButton under the .container. In your case you should change the .container with parent div of the accordions